# Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in angular template driven form

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

component html:

```
 <form novalidate #composeMsgForm="ngForm">
   <div class="form-group">
            <span class="cmpsMsgsub">
              <input name="subject" required maxlength='128' #subject = "ngModel"  [ngModel] = "msgSubject" placeholder="Subject" id='subject' class="subjectInput searchTerm">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="subject.invalid && (subject.dirty || subject.touched)" class="error">
              <div [hidden]="!subject.errors.required">
                  Subject is required!
              </div>
              <div [hidden]="!subject.errors.maxlength">
                  Subject cannot be more than 128 characters long.
              </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

In component.ts I added:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
declare let jQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: "app-user",
  templateUrl: "./app-user.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app-user.component.css"]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
}
```

I am getting error in console:

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (UserComponent.ngfactory.js:701)
>       at Object.updateRenderer (core.es5.js:12720)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)

I do not understand what I have done wrong.
I have followed [tutplus angular4 template driven form](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-forms-in-angular-4-template-driven-forms--cms-29766)
I am using angular 4+

Comment: Where do you use `value`?

Comment: Not accessing value anywhere.

Comment: If you click on your error it should show you the place where the error comes from

Comment: Yes I have written this line in html {{ composeMsgForm.value | json }}. Removing it solved the issue. thanks alot for your time again @yurzui, you always help! But why it was giving error, could not understand.

Comment: Seems somehow composeMsgForm is not defined yet, You can try using safe navigation operator `{{ composeMsgForm?.value | json }}`